# Add custom items and logo to Magento 2 Mobile Menu

Tags: html, css, mobile, magento2

Has anyone been able to achieve this? I'm looking to add custom menu items that do not show up in the desktop site.

I sketched a mockup so I could illustrate. Any advice appreciated!

[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I60d7.png)

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @themanwhoknowstheman See my answer below!

Answer (score 4):

You can add to the parent block which is found on line 65 in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`.

Add the following files to your theme.

> app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">                
    <body>                    
        <referenceBlock name="store.menu">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu.logo" template="Magento_Theme::html/mobile_menu_logo.phtml" after="catalog.topnav" />                    
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>        
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/mobile_menu_logo.phtml

```html
<!-- content goes here -->
```